# Expected area "sweeped" on an infinite Minesweeper board

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics

Given an average density (x/y) of x mines in y squares, is it possible to calculate the expected number of squares you can "sweep" (i.e. identify whether there is a mine or not) on an infinitely sized minesweeper game, before you have to guess- i.e. no more squares can be deduced.

Comment: But i don’t really understand how the minesweeper game works: sometimes when you press on one square, some squares in its vicinity with no mines would also be automatically pressed.

Comment: One interesting part of your question is at what density the expected area swept diverges, and the asymptotic form of the divergence.

Comment: To fully clarify the question (in case there are different implementations of the game): Every square contains a mine independently of all other squares with probability $p=\frac xy$, except the first square we click on, which is guaranteed not to contain a mine -- correct?

Comment: @joriki Yes I realised afterwards that was a far easier wording, I will edit now

Comment: I have changed it back, because due to the nature of the game (where some squares being a mine implies that other squares cannot be), surely there cannot be an independent probability p?

Comment: If $p$ is small enough, then with positive probability your first click will reveal an infinitely large portion of the grid. (This follows from percolation theory.) In this case, you may not be able to sweep in finitely many step before a guess is needed.

Comment: @SangchulLee: That's what I meant above. There is a threshold at which the expected area you can sweep diverges. This could be the site percolation threshold for the square lattice, or it could be a higher threshold.

Comment: @Oddlyasymmetric: I don't understand the problem you raise in your last comment. Before you see any numbers, how does a mine on some square imply that other squares can't have one? Of course once you see numbers, there are such implications, but that doesn't keep us from generating the original board (which determines those very numbers) with independent choices.

Comment: @joriki, You are right. Given the 1-dependence, I guess the threshold (if exists) can be different from that of the site percolation on $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but I thought it would be interesting to do a simulation on a finite board.

So I made a bare-bones Minesweeper solver and ran a 1000 games for various mine densities on a 50x50 board and got the following:

[image]

The X axis shows the mine density (i.e. the probability that a square is a mine) and the Y axis shows the percentage of mines swept.

As can be seen, the steepness of the curve is quite large. At a density of 0.13 it is at 90% and at 0.22 it is under 10%.

To check how good (or bad) my algorithm was, I manually played 10 games of Minesweeper at expert level (where mine density is less than 0.21) and got the result of 53%. This is almost twice as good as my algorithm which got 27%. But the steepness of the curve means my primitive algorithm got 57% at the slightly lower density of 0.18.

So, even with a better Minesweeper solver I expect the basic curve shape will be the same, just shifted a bit to the right.